# An interesting problem with the infinite product for $\arccos \alpha $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, infinite-product

The following infinite product is well known:

$ (1) \frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{\arccos \alpha} = \frac{\sqrt{2+2\alpha}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\alpha}}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\alpha}}}}{2}...$

For $\alpha \neq 1$

This gives an infinite product for $\arccos \alpha$ similar to Viete's formula for $\pi$.

The question is the following: is there any way to get a similar infinite product for $\cos \alpha$ in terms of $\alpha$ and nested square roots by using some process of inversion applied to formula $(1)$ for $\arccos \alpha$?

If yes, is it always possible to derive a similar representation (infinite series, infinite product, continued fraction, etc.) for a function or its inverse, if we have a representation of one of them?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you give me a link where they show this nice infinite product. I never saw it before. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, @ClaudeLeibovici. You can see this infinite product in the following link: https://corkteeth.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/a-complete-view-of-vic3a8te-like-infinite-products-with-fibonacci-and-lucas-numbers.pdf (is formula 3.3